# Why do `ip` and `ifconfig` have different behaviors when the interface is down?

Tags: ip, routing, ifconfig

I first shutdown interfaces

```
# Shutdown the interfaces
ip link set enp2s0f0 down
ip link set enp2s0f1 down
```

### Using `ifconfig`:

```
# Set subnets to interfaces
ifconfig enp2s0f0 10.0.0.1/24
ifconfig enp2s0f1 10.0.1.1/24

# Add two routes
ip route add 10.11.1.1 dev enp2s0f0
ip route add 10.11.0.1 dev enp2s0f1

# Result => NO PROBLEM, my routes are here even tho the interfaces are down
$ip route
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp2s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 
10.0.1.0/24 dev enp2s0f1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.1 
10.11.0.1 dev enp2s0f1 scope link 
10.11.1.1 dev enp2s0f0 scope link
```

### Using `ip`:

```
# Set subnets to interfaces
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev enp2s0f0
ip addr add 10.0.1.1/24 dev enp2s0f1

$ip route
#NOTHING => Where are the routes?!

# Add two routes
ip route add 10.11.1.1 dev enp2s0f0
ip route add 10.11.0.1 dev enp2s0f1

$ip route
#NOTHING => Where are my routes?!

ip link set enp2s0f0 up
ip link set enp2s0f1 up

# Result => WOW only two routes appeared miraculously
$ip route
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp2s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 
10.0.1.0/24 dev enp2s0f1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.1 
# => Where are my 10.11.*.* routes?
```

1. Why doesn't `ip route` show my routes?
2. Where are my routes added miraculously after I bring my interfaces up? Why can't I see them before?
3. Why don't my routes show up after I bring the interfaces up?

I want to set up all the routes before I bring the interfaces up. I don't have any issue with `ifconfig` doing so. I wonder what surprises will come up next.

I thought `ifconfig` and `ip` were compatible, the move from ifconfig to ip won't be so easy.

Comment: Hint: `ifconfig INTERFACE ADDRESS` implies the `up` option, so your `ifconfig` way is actually bringing up the interface before you add the routes.  From the [`ifconfig` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ifconfig): "_**up:** This flag causes the interface to be activated. It is implicitly specified if an address is assigned to the interface._"

Comment: Roger! Thanks! Please write it in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All three of your questions stem from one misunderstanding:

**`ifconfig` with an interface and an address implies the `up` option**, so in your `ifconfig` example, the interface is coming up at the same time you specify an address for it.

This means

```
ifconfig enp2s0f0 10.0.0.1/24
ifconfig enp2s0f1 10.0.1.1/24
```

is actually short for

```
ifconfig enp2s0f0 10.0.0.1/24 up
ifconfig enp2s0f1 10.0.1.1/24 up
```

---

`ip` from [iproute2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2) more cleanly organizes the acts of:

- bringing an **interface** up and taking it down (`ip link`),
- assigning an IP **address** to a network device (`ip address`), and
- configuring the kernel **routing** tables (`ip route`).

`ifconfig` mixes those disparate concepts together, which is arguably more confusing or less intuitive.

---

If you want a convenient way to manage the state of routes, network devices, interfaces, and tunnels, you should consider using a network configuration management tool.  **They let you define your network in a convenient declarative syntax, which you can quickly bring up or down with one command.**

These are the some of the tools included with common Linux distributions:

- Debian – [ifupdown](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html) (`/etc/network/interfaces`, `/etc/network/interfaces.d/`)
- Ubuntu – [netplan.io](https://netplan.io/) (`/etc/netplan/`)
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux / CentOS – [ifcfg](https://web.archive.org/web/20190920042640/https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/configuring_and_managing_networking/index#configuring-ip-networking-with-ifcfg-files_configuring-and-managing-networking) (`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`)
- usually distros with desktop environments – [NetworkManager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager) (`/etc/NetworkManager/`)

---

For completeness, here are the answers to your questions:

> 1. Why doesn't `ip route` show my routes?

Routes are not saved into the main table if the corresponding link is down.  Your `ip` command sequence does not bring up the involved interfaces first.

> 2. Where are my routes added miraculously after I bring my interfaces up? Why can't I see them before?

The routes of a device are not registered in the routing table if the interface is down.

> 3. Why don't my routes show up after I bring the interfaces up?

The routes were not added because the corresponding interfaces had to be up first.  You should have seen an error message like `RTNETLINK answers: Network is down` or `Error: Device for nexthop is not up.` if your route add was attempted on a down interface. The return code (`$?`) should also have been non-zero.

> I want to set up all the routes before I bring the interfaces up.

As far as I can tell, this cannot be done, even with `ifconfig`.  Remember that your `ifconfig` commands are actually bringing up the interfaces before you add the routes.

> I wonder what surprises will come up next.

Hopefully none.  `ip`'s separation of concerns makes a lot of sense if you [get to know it](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ip).

> I thought `ifconfig` and `ip` were compatible

The two commands have some overlap, but they are not interchangeable.

Comment: I use this custom temporary scripts for hardware testing combined with iptables to tamper packets. For that purpose, I disable the management of specific interfaces using `nmcli`. Thanks!

Comment: As an app improvement, `ip` commands should return something instead of ignoring the command. I'll focus more on the ip manual ;)

Comment: @Alexis_FR_JP: You should be getting a message that says `RTNETLINK answers: Network is down` or `Error: Device for nexthop is not up.` if your route add was attempted on a down interface. The return code (`$?`) should also be non-zero.